# Cat6 Ethernet connections

Tags: connector, ethernet, cables

I have been trying to create my own [CAT6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_6_cable) cable lengths, but have been having problems with achieving a connection.

Every diagram that I have seen online doesn't match my wires exactly.

I have an orange, blue, green and brown solid wires. When you strip the protective sheathing off, each color is twisted with a solid white wire, not striped like every diagram shows and explains.

The outside of the sheath says CAT6 and I have been using CAT6 connector but every time I make a connector, I am not registering a connection once it is plugged in.

Someone mentioned that maybe I'm not crimping down hard enough, so I even went as far as to strip down the sheathing on each individual wire to help with connections and that didn't help.

I've made sure that, when I am inserting the wire, they are not crossing.  The order in which I am inserting them into the connector is:

white
orange
white
blue
white
green
white
brown

If anyone can help, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: https://www.lanshack.com/make_cat_6_cable.aspx

Comment: Are you making sure that you keep the correct white wire paired with correct color wire, to keep the wire pairs in order?

Comment: There is much more to making a good CAT6 cable than getting the wire colors right. Are you saying that the cables don't work at any speed, or they don't work at the highest CAT6 speeds?

Comment: your sequence of wires may incorrect .... please indicate exactly the sequence of wires ... the sequence that you included in your question is unclear .... do not strip insulation from the wires, it may cause loose connections

Answer (score 4):

The eight wires in the cable are set up as four twisted pairs, as you've stated. Generally the pair colors are matched with solid and stripes wires of the same color; e.g. Blue and White-blue (striped or dotted), Orange and White-orange, etc.

Even if your cable doesn't include the striped markings, the wire pairing is critical. When building your cables, make sure that you use the *correct* white wire in any specific location. You can determine which is correct by noting which colored wire it is twisted with.

If you are already doing this, the next step would be to post close-up pictures of your cable and connectors, and we'll go on from there. You can edit the pictures into your original post by clicking the "edit" link directly under your question.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, your wiring order could be incorrect. 
T568A or B on both ends is a straight through cable. B is the most common. If you hold the cable so that the cable runs down your arm and the exposed ends are in your hand, from left to right, you want W/O, O, W/G, Bl, W/Bl, G, W/br, br.

If you're trying to do CAT6A/CAT7 (so 10g) there are two standards. The first standard is a typical CAT5 cable with a heftier connection and higher MHZ cable that is shielded and grounded. The connector will have a metal shield and the cable has a metal grounding wire through the center of it (as well as metal shielding). The metal wire should not be cut! This metal wire needs to be connected to the metal shield on both ends. This grounds the card to the switch.
The second standard is completely different and requires a separate set of tools. The 4 pairs of wires go on the outside corners of the jack and not flat across the jack. This also has a metal grounding wire and metal shields on the connectors, but the switches/cards and not reverse compatible with older CAT5 cable.

Answer (score 0):

Cat6 is a standardised twisted pair cable for use in Ethernet and other networks.

[image]

Source [Fibresales](https://fibresales.com.au/)

Cat 6 patch cables are normally terminated in 8P8C modular connectors, using either T568A for horizontal cables or T568Bpin to match the older AT&T assignments.

[image]

Source [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIA/EIA-568#T568A_and_T568B_termination)

The only difference between these configurations is that pairs 2 and 3 (orange and green) are swapped. The cables pins are typically a “straight-through” configuration.

Performance is compatible as long as both ends of a cable are terminated exactly the same.

Being the sixth version of twisted pair Ethernet cabling, CAT6 was created in order to support the Gigabit Ethernet Data rates. It has been designed with a bandwidth of up to 250MHz.

It has 4 pairs of copper wire and all 4 pairs are used in Gigabit Ethernet applications.

The main feature is that it can support 10 Gigabit Ethernet connections for a distance of  37-55 meters (depending on crosstalk).

**The benefits of Cat6 cable are numerous.**

- Cat6 cable is backwards compatible with the Category 5, Category 5e, and Category 3 cable standards.

  This means it can work with older systems without the need for a complete technological upgrade.
- As with previous cable versions, CAT6 cable also uses the same RJ-45 standard connector.
- Cat6 cables are more tightly wound and can feature 2 or more twists per cm, depending on the manufacturer.
- Cat6 cables also have a thicker sheath in comparison to Cat5e cables.

  This helps protect the cables against Near-End Crosstalk (NEXT) and Alien Crosstalk (AXT).
- Cat6 technology uses all four pairs to achieve its high levels of performance.
- Cat6 cables are used regularly for computer networking, security systems, and even phone services.

The benefits of Cat6 does not stop there. Its performance is better and more versatile.

**Cat6 improvements.**

The improvements made from Cat5 to Cat6 include:

-more available bandwidth,

- higher reliability,
- increased data rates,
- and a better signal-to-noise ratio.

That means better reliability and fewer errors and data losses.

It’s, therefore, no surprise that this category of cable became the obvious preference for those operating in network installations.

**Conclusion.**

Constructed to provide Ethernet transmission speeds of up to 10 Gbps, so when you need speed, Category 6 (Cat6) Ethernet cable is up to the task.